# Nodejs Generate document on BE and send to user (FE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, document, generate

I don't have any idea how to handle this so I have no code to show, I only need (I think ) some guidance.
I have a nodeJs server (API) and a vueJs frontend.
I have an endpoint that give me a summary (it change from user to user ) and the data comes from mongodb, I would like to export/generate a pdf / doc. how can I do it? What are the steps ? (I would like to have an EP to generate the document and download it ) do I need to create a template with ejs for example ? What after ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to generate the document in the backend using some sort of node PDF generation library. You can create an html page with ejs to loop through the items and make a PDF of it using [pdf-creator-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node) package. Most of the examples are shown in the linked docs for making PDF's with some markup.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

You can try to capture the Data in FrontEnd (i assume it would be a json format), and then use some jquery Plugin on the front end to generate the doc in desired format,
example plugin [enter link description here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/export-table-json-csv-txt-pdf.html)

OR

**Option 2**

Generate the Document using npm package such as [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-generator-api-client)

Ideally and importantly secured way would be **Option 2**

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create a pdf document in your Node API and that can be tedious work. But with some time you should be able to get it.

You have 2 options: pdfkit and pdf-creator-node (both are npm packages). I would use pdf-creator-node because you can use templates (not sure if you can do that in pdfkit).

1. Install the package

   `npm i pdf-creator-node`
2. Create template.html

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
        <mate charest="utf-8" />
         <title>Hello world</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <h1>Example List</h1>
        <ul>
           {{#each person}}
           <li>Name: {{this.name}}</li>
           <li>Age: {{this.age}}</li>
           <br>
           {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. In your node file add

   ```
    var pdf = require("pdf-creator-node")
    var fs = require('fs')
    var html = fs.readFileSync('template.html', 'utf8')
   ```
4. Create the size/options for your pdf

   `var options = { format: "A3", orientation: "portrait", border: "10mm" };`

   Check the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node) for more details about format
5. Create your list of people

   ```
   var users = [
   {
       name:"foo",
       age:"30"
   },
   {
       name:"bar",
       age:"22"
   },
   {
       name:"baz",
       age:"9"
   }
   ]
   var document = {
   html: html,
   data: {
       users: users
   },
   path: "./output.pdf"
   };
   ```
6. Then lastly use `pdf.create` to make the pdf

   ```
   pdf.create(document, options)
   .then(res => {
       console.log(res)
    })
   .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
   });
   ```

Then you would use something like `res.sendfile(output.pdf)` to send it to the client-side or however you want to do that

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot! I finished by using [node-html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf).
Do you think there is a way to generate and download without save it on disk? Because i don't need to keep the PDF on server side, only need to generate and download it (at the moment all works but I keep/save the file on disk ... )
Thanks @MaxGertner

Comment: Hm, good point. I'm not entirely sure though. You could have a constant file name that just gets overwritten every time you need to generate a new pdf. Then you can just convert the pdf into a blob and sent the blob to the client-side

Comment: Hi @MaxGertner, I took a look at node-html-pdf, but i did not see nothing about filling the html with parameters .. Is it only for static resources?